# Why Elastic is slow when search with like and or?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elastic for searh on big data. (over billion rows but just 2 columns : id and caption)

When I search id keyword it is fast but if I search text on caption with 'like' it it takes long time.

slow search case:

```
       CAPTION LIKE '%TES%'
    OR CAPTION LIKE '%ASD%'
    OR CAPTION LIKE '%DSSS%'
    OR CAPTION LIKE '%VBCVB%'
    OR CAPTION LIKE '%ASDAS%'
    OR CAPTION LIKE '%GDGDF%'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to do a full scan of the whole index to check if every single term matches or not.
That's why it's clearly indicated in the documentation that it's slow.

It's better to use a ngram based strategy if you want faster results but this comes with a price at index time of more time to index the content and more disk space.

A compromise could be not using the first `%` sign like:

```
   CAPTION LIKE 'TES%'
OR CAPTION LIKE 'ASD%'
OR CAPTION LIKE 'DSSS%'
OR CAPTION LIKE 'VBCVB%'
OR CAPTION LIKE 'ASDAS%'
OR CAPTION LIKE 'GDGDF%'
```

As Elasticsearch can then do some optimisation that will not check every single term in the index but only a subset.

Comment: thanks for answer, I do not know  ngram based strategy, I will search it now

Comment: Although old, you can read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html